# Как вывести данные из API JSON? | Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, minecraft

Есть ссылка (api JSON) в ней есть данные, NAME и ID.
Как я могу получить ID?

https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/Steve

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Steve = textBox1.Text;
    string UUID = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + Steve;
    textBox2.Text = UUID + "     " + Steve;
    button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(45, 45, 45);


}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Десериализовать пробовали?

Comment: Я не знаю что это такое.

Comment: Уважаемый, поймите, сайт на котором вы находитесь, не является форумом или фриланс биржей, где вы даете задачу, а вам ее решают, нет! Это сайт, где сообщество совместными силами собирает полезную (не только авторам) информацию. И тут важно понимать, что **за вас решать не будут**! Подскажут, да; помогут исправить, да; но не решать за вас. Поэтому берите свою ссылку и идите пытайтесь самостоятельно, а уж когда все опробовали, приходите, поможем. И да "я не знаю" - читайте значит базовые понятия языка, начните с задач попроще, а то уже 3-й вопрос и везде "я не знаю" ... серьезно?